# JmonkeyEngine gradlew build doesn't work

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

I am beginner in JMonkeyEngine. I cloned the repository [JMonkeyEngine SDK based on Netbeans](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/sdk), then I ran `./ gradlew build` in the terminal and returned this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/www/html/programas/sdk/build.gradle' line: 346

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'sdk'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':optlibs'.
   > Could not resolve org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-jbullet:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-jbullet:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT.
         > Could not parse POM /home/jramirez/.m2/repository/org/jmonkeyengine/jme3-jbullet/3.2.0-SNAPSHOT/jme3-jbullet-3.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
            > Unable to resolve version for dependency 'jbullet:jbullet:jar'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
```

java version

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

What happened or What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you tried `./gradlew run`?

Comment: Yes! it returns the same Exception...

Comment: Note that you don't need to (and shouldn't) build the SDK yourself, especially if you just want to try it out. Here you find the complete installable package: https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/sdk/releases

Comment: I Currently use linux s.o

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [readme](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/sdk/blob/master/readme.md) to get all dependencies you need to call at first time

```
 build_engine.sh
```

> Note: Currently, the SDK has to build the engine on it's own, because not all needed dependencies are in mavenCentral/jCenter. Thus you have to call build_engine.sh first on a Linux System, Inside your Windows-Git-Shell or you can manually checkout the jMonkeyEngine repository and then invoke gradlew.bat -PbuildJavaDoc=true install. This will add all jMonkeyEngine Libraries into your local maven "server".

And then

```
 ./gradlew run
```

> If you just want to run the SDK on your machine

Comment: Ok, I'am running it, I've readed the README already.. and it show several options to continue, which could be ?

Comment: `./gradlew run` If you just want to run the SDK on your machine

Comment: the solution was download the version 3.1.0, earlier I intalled the 3.2.0